axios error when connecting to the server and post error
I'm setting up a social network as a fullstack training project, I made the frontend, connected it to the database and made the feed, when I clicked "send", the comment I placed to appear in the posts would be updated below, here's the error console and the script that I think is where the error is

const handlePostSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("//localhost:8000/users", {
        username: newPostText, // Verifique o nome do campo que sua API espera
        email: "test@example.com" // Adicione outros campos necessários
      });
      console.log("Postagem criada com sucesso:", response.data);
  
      // Atualiza a lista de postagens após criar uma nova postagem
      const fetchPosts = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get("//localhost:8000/users");
          setPosts(response.data); // Atualiza o estado com as postagens recebidas do backend
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Erro ao buscar postagens:", error);
        }
      };
  
      fetchPosts(); // Chama a função de busca de postagens ao montar o componente
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Erro ao criar postagem:", error);
    }
  };

I thought it could be the url, but I tried a few ways, when I passed "localhost:8000/users" the post came out but then axios couldn't find the url

You have a "cors" error, your Webinterface run on port 3000 but Server in 8000 you must configure cors in your golang server

The image is hardly readable. Please add the relevant parts as text to your question via [edit].
